# Ask for # of variables based on input (for/while statement?)

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, while-loop

Is there was a way to ask the user to input a certain number of variables based on an earlier user input. I don't want to make an if statement for every possible user input, because that is messy and tedious.

I am asking the user for a grid size, and then I want to ask them to fill each box with a number.

I was thinking I could use a for or while statement to keep asking the user for a new number until the height and width of the grid was reached, but I don't know how to only ask for one variable at a time, then change the variable name the next time it asks the user (the next time it loops).

I kinda want it to work like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter next number");
    (variable+1)=scan.nextInt();
}
```

And save each variable in an increasing order.

Comment: When you want to store a whole bunch of related items, think about using an array (if you know how many) or a `List` (if you don't).

Comment: You can't increment the variable name like that in Java. If you want to store multiple inputs, you could add each one into a `List` or an array to use later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two "cookbook" solutions for such a case are either use an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
int[] numbers = new int[height];
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter next number: ");
    numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Or some sort of a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html), such as an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(height);
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter next number: ");
    numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
}
```